# Finding if there is a space in a list(return boolean value)

Tags: python

Looking for some help on a tick tac toe exercise:

I have the bellow:

test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','','O','X']

```
def space_check(board,position):
    free_space = ""
    if free_space in board[position]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When running the function I cannot see the False return, only True:

```
space_check(test_board,7)
Output: True
space_check(test_board,9)
Output: True
```

Comment: try using `print(space_check)`

Comment: Think I've managed to solve it. Needed to assign free_space = " " instead of ""

Comment: oh ok. Good to see that you have solved it yourself.

Comment: You compare against a string, not against a list. The empty string is in every string.

Answer (score 0):

`If free_space in board[position]`

You are search a "" in a string not in a list of string,so the results always true because "" always exist in any string.

You just Use equal operation `==` instead of `in`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function with this:

```
def space_check(board,position):
    free_space = ""
    return free_space == board[position]

test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','','O','X']
space_check(test_board, 7)
Output : True

space_check(test_board, 9)
Output: False
```

Comment: Note that there is no point in using an if to decide between booleans. Just return the result of the test directly: `return board[position] == ""`

Comment: Yes, you're right